# JSON feed to Drop Down with jQuery IE7

Tags: jquery, json, select

I am trying to populate a Drop Down Select element with Jquery using a JSON feed from accessdb (a great Javascript libuary for accessing an access .mdb file as a local database).

My HTML:

```
<select id="instructors"></select>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){



     var myDB = new ACCESSdb("accessdb.mdb", {showErrors:true});

     var instructorquery = "SELECT * FROM Instructors";

     var instructorJson = myDB.query(instructorquery, {json:true});
     $.each(instructorJson, function(key, value) {   
                    $('#instructors').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));  
    });


});
```

The output from alert(instructorJson) is:

```
[{"ID":"1","Name":"Capt Hogg","Date last completed":"8/4/2013"},{"ID":"2","Name":"Capt Baker","Date last completed":"8/4/2013"}]
```

So the feed is working. IE7 is throwing an error of 'Object Expected'.

I admit to being a learner so forgive me if my error is obvious.

**EDIT Palash's answer below works in modern browsers. I found a solution for IE7 (see below).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by adding in JSON.parse and using Douglas Crockfords Json2 Library [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js):
(This is an IE7 fix, Palashs' answer works for decent browsers).

```
$(document).ready(function(){



 var myDB = new ACCESSdb("accessdb.mdb", {showErrors:true});

 var instructorquery = "SELECT * FROM Instructors";

 var instructor = myDB.query(instructorquery, {json:true});
var instructorJson = JSON.parse(instructor);
 $.each(instructorJson, function (key, value) {
$('#instructors').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.ID).text(value.Name));
});
    });
```

Thanks for your support Palash

I hate IE ;(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each(instructorJson, function (key, value) {
    $('#instructors').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", value.ID).text(value.Name));
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6PmzC/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I still get nothing and error in IE7. 'Line 19 Char 70 Object expected.'

Comment: Sorry miss communication I am afraid that didnt work for me. I still get nothing in the dropdown and an IE error of `line: 19 Char: 70 Object expected`

Comment: Unfortunately jsFiddle does not event work on my IE7!! I will have a look at this again a decent browser in an hour or so, thanks.

Comment: Yes, the demo is working for me in Chrome. So, try once in a different browser!

Comment: Any ideas what might make IE7 not like it? I have read that IE7 does not like trailing semi colons. But I have tried the function many ways with no luck.

Comment: Not sure why this is happening in IE7. I am using IE10 now and have not seen/used IE7 for ages :)

Comment: Works beautifully in other browsers. Ill keep trying IE7, it may be a jquery issue. Do you know how i could render the html with pure Javascript?